# SQLEXPRESS: Bounding box from geometry

Tags: sql, geometry, sql-server-express, varbinary, bounding-box

I need for numeric values added to my view (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) number values.
The table has geometry as a varbinary(max) value.

How would i get the bbox values from geometry field?

thanx for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've understood, you can use `SUBSTRING()` on your `varbinary` column to extract individual bound values and then cast the result to `int` (if they are `int`).

Something like this:

```
SELECT xmin = CAST(SUBSTRING(bbox, xmin_start_pos, xmin_byte_length) AS int)
FROM ...
```